# Как сделать редактор текста todo list?

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

Есть самый обычный Todo проект, с кнопками удалить и обновить статус задачи.

Вопрос: как можно реализовать кнопку редактирование текста задачи?

**screen:**
[image: todo]

**code controller:**

```
package com.example.todos.controller;

@Controller
public class TodoController {
    private TodoRepository todoRepository;

    public TodoController(TodoRepository todoRepository) {
      this.todoRepository = todoRepository;
}

@GetMapping
public String index(){
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/todos")
public String todos(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("todos", todoRepository.findAll());
    return "todos";
}

@PostMapping("/todoNew")
public String add(@RequestParam String todoItem,
                  @RequestParam String status, Model model){
    Todo todo = new Todo();
    todo.setTodoItem(todoItem);
    todo.setCompleted(status);
    todoRepository.save(todo);
    model.addAttribute("todos", todoRepository.findAll());
    return "redirect:/todos";
}

@PostMapping("todoDelete/{id}")
public String delete(@PathVariable long id, Model model){
    todoRepository.deleteById(id);
    model.addAttribute("todos", todoRepository.findAll());
    return "redirect:/todos";
}

@PostMapping("/todoUpdate/{id}")
public String update(@PathVariable long id, Model model){
    Todo todo = todoRepository.findById(id).get();
    if("Yes".equals(todo.getCompleted())) {
        todo.setCompleted("No");
    }
    else {
        todo.setCompleted("Yes");
    }
    todoRepository.save(todo);
    model.addAttribute("todos", todoRepository.findAll());
    return "redirect:/todos";
}

@PutMapping("/edit")
public String editTask(@PathVariable String todoItem,  Model model){
    Todo todo = new Todo();
    todo.setTodoItem(todoItem);
    todoRepository.save(todo);
    return "redirect:/todos";

}
```

}

**code html(thymeleaf):**

```html
<section id="todocontainer">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Id</th>
                <th scope="col">Todo</th>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
                <th scope="col">Update</th>
                <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                <th scope="col">Edit</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr th:each="todo : ${todos}">
                <th scope="row" th:text=${todo.id}></th>
                <td th:text=${todo.todoItem}></td>
                <td th:text=${todo.completed}></td>
                <td>
                    <form th:action="@{/todoUpdate/{id}(id=${todo.id})}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm text-white">Update</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form th:action="@{/todoDelete/{id}(id=${todo.id})}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm text-white">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg text-white" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewModal">Add New Todo</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
<!-- View Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="viewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">TODO</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form th:action="@{/todoNew}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Todo</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="todoItem" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Todo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Status</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="status">
                            <option>Yes</option>
                            <option>No</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Todo</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавить ещё одну кнопку:

```xhtml
<td>
  <form th:action="@{/edit/{id}(id=${todo.id})}" method="GET">
     <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm text-white">Edit</button>
     </div>
  </form>
</td>
```